# Newbie trying a react.js project. When I try to import an image I get an error message that it failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> ./src/components/Page/Page.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> './Page/baby.jpeg' in '/Users/kim/Desktop/untitled folder
> 2/Development/Academy/Projects/portfolio/src/components/Page'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Page.css';
import baby from './Page/baby.jpeg';

class LandingPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div name='page' className='Page'>
                <h1>Hello,.</h1>
                {/* <hr className='break' */}
                <p>WELCOME</p>
                <img src={baby} width="100" height="50" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: In react we don't import images like this. try require function like require("../path_to_image");

Comment: Hey Shamika, your code seems to be fine, the only issue could be with the path which you are trying to reference or the folder name. Try looking into that. If possible try sharing a sample code on codesandbox and we might be able to help better. Rest assured your code is just fine it's only the path that is creating the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the image location referencing.

If your folder structure is like this

```
Page -> LandingPage.js
Page -> Page.css
Page -> baby.jpeg
```

Then you should import the image like this

```
import baby from './baby.jpeg';
```

This should solve your path reference issue because LandingPage component is in the same folder as that of image.

Here is a sample codesandbox with these assumptions

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-snowflake-dp8z1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding the iframe but that didn't work. Here is the link. Thanks for informing. https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-snowflake-dp8z1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you've gathered this from the comments, but you need to ensure you have the correct path for "baby.jpeg." It should look in the local directory to find the resource(relative path) unless you specifically give it a global path. Since the "baby.jpeg" is supposed to be in "Page" with your code, perhaps you should try using the path "./baby.jpeg" or change to a global path.